# Focus Which not triggered by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger an action when focusing an input but the focus event not come from click?

```
$('#input').focus(function(){
  if(not come from click)
  {
    alert('Holla!');
  }
});
```

Comment: can you paste code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tell between "focus" events that come from keyboard and those that come from mouse, you can track the mouse events.

First, to understand the sequence of events that happen when you click an input, or Tab into it, look at the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orlenko/fyFkk/

In it, we'll log mousedown, mouseup, click, focus, and blur events.\

```
<input type="text" id="zero"/>
<input type="text" id="one"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var one = $('#one');

    one.mousedown(function() {
       console.log('mousedown');
    });

    one.mouseup(function() {
       console.log('mouseup');
    });

    one.click(function() {
       console.log('click');
    });

    one.focus(function() {
       console.log('focus');
    });

    one.blur(function() {
       console.log('blur');
    });

});
```

If we simply click on the input, and then on another control, we'll get the following:

- mousedown
- focus
- mouseup
- click
- blur

But if we tab into and out of the input, we'll see in the console:

- focus
- blur

So, if we keep track of mousedown and blur events, we can tell between a keyboard-based focus and a mouse-based one. For example:

```
$(function() {
    var one = $('#one');

    one.mousedown(function() {
       console.log('mousedown');
        $(this).data('mousedown', true);
    });

    one.mouseup(function() {
       console.log('mouseup');
    });

    one.click(function() {
       console.log('click');
    });

    one.focus(function() {
        if ($(this).data('mousedown')) {
            console.log('You clicked it!');
        } else {
            console.log('You tabbed it!');
        }
    });

    one.blur(function() {
       console.log('blur');
       $(this).data('mousedown', false);
    });

});
```

A fiddle with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/orlenko/cwRAw/

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup`

```
 $('#input').keyup(function(){
    alert('Called only when the focus is on element through keypress');
 });
```

Comment: The problem with `keyup` is that it fires *after* focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ren(){

    alert('Holla!');

}
$('input').focus(ren);
$('input').mousedown(function(){      
$('input').off('focus',ren);  
});
$('input').mouseup(function(){      
$('input').on('focus',ren);  
});
```

Don't check in focus function instead remove the focus function when making a click

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK/30/)

Comment: Your function send the browser into an infinite alert loop.